# GitLab CI: how to simulate user input from console

Tags: python, gitlab-ci

I have a .gitlab-ci.yml similar to this:

```
image: python:3.6

before_script:
- pip install -r .requirements

test:
  script:
  - python main.py --arg myArg
```

The python script main.py is a command line program and expects some input from the user, which is requested with `input`:

```
userName = input("Please input your name:")
```

I know that maybe I shouldn't call that python script for continuous integration and I also have unit tests for all other scripts which can be tested fine. But nevertheless, I would like to know, if it is possible
to somehow simulate the user input by specifying it in the yml itself.

Somebody any idea?

Comment: Pipe? Redirect from file? Even `cat` would do the job.

Comment: @KlausD.: is this a question or an answer? If you know it better, then please show how.

Answer (score 0):

`python main.py --arg myArg < answersFile.txt` or...

`printf "Answer1\nAnswer2\nAnswer3\n" | /path/to/main.py --arg myArg`.

---

These will run main.py and input answers in the order they are asked.